# Multiple columns with identical row heights in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website where the designer has asked for the following format on the homepage:

```
News     Notices  Events
Item 1   Item 1   Item 1
Blurb    Blurb    Blurb
Blurb             Blurb
Blurb

Item 2   Item 2   Item 2
Blurb    Blurb    Blurb
Blurb    Blurb
         Blurb
```

The idea is that each item should be of the same horizontal height. I can easily do this with divs in the following way:

```
<div class="row">
  <div>News</div>
  <div>Notices</div>
  <div>Events</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

However, this isn't great information architecture - especially as I want to stack the News, Notices and Events column for small/narrow/mobile screens.

Is there anyway I can get the outcome the designer wants but still retain the correct information architecture?

**Update**

After using jQuery to readjust the grid on page load I showed the designer. Once he realised we have very little control on what users put in the CMS and the content in the grid was going to be unbalanced he canned the whole idea.

So I don't need the answer to this but I'll keep it up out of curiosity.

Comment: same horizontal height ? That's like a square circle :D Why not use tables and specify the height ?

Comment: @danontheline - a table wouldn't resize correctly for small/ mobile screens.

Comment: You could target mobile devices with a different stylesheet? This article lists three possibilities http://www.gethifi.com/blog/three-ways-to-target-mobile-devices.

Comment: @Jan-Henk - I'm using a different stylesheet for mobile devices. But if the HTML in my example or a table is used I won't be able to stack News, Notices and Events.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following. Should give you some ideas:

http://spyrestudios.com/css-grid-systems/